# Capistrano run task without having to set an environment

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm currently trying to run a custom cap task in v3.0.1 without having to use a stage in the call. However it always returns:

Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.

If I run it with a stage, so production/staging it works fine.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: As I understand it, this is by design in cap 3. If it doesn't matter what stage you are dealing with (i.e., which servers you are talking to), maybe what you want is a rake task and not a cap task.